# Android Binder and its possibilities

Tags: android, process, ipc, rpc, android-binder

I have a question related to Android's Binder component.
When I use an Android App on the emulator is it possible to do a remote procedure call of a service that is offered by a running local server (written in java).
Is the inter process communication with the Binder also working with a non-android app?

Or do you know other possibilities to do RPC's with Android?

Answer (score 1):

There are several IPC mechanisms in android: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740324/what-are-the-ipc-mechanisms-in-android) you can find information about them. Moreover, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428730/can-we-use-system-ipc-in-android-ndk-code/11429558#11429558) I described what IPC mechanisms of Unix you can use in Android native applications.